# Am I correctly writing code for curve fitting models? The line is way off for every model except for linear regression

Tags: python, python-2.7, regression, curve-fitting, exponential

I'm very new to coding in python and could use some support in answering this question. I wrote the code for the problem, but my models do not look correct.

**Below is the question:**

Optimization - Curve Fit Given 16 pairs of prices (as dependent variable) and
corresponding demands (as independent variable), use the curve fitting tool to estimate the best fitting
linear, exponential, logarithmic, and power curves.

Price Demand
127 3420
134 3400
136 3250
139 3410
140 3190
141 3250
148 2860
149 2830
151 3160
154 2820
155 2780
157 2900
159 2810
167 2580
168 2520
171 2430

**Below is my code:**

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import *
from scipy.optimize import *
# linear regression
#called in curve fitting model
def linreg(x,a,b):
    return a*x+b

# data

x = [3420, 3400, 3250, 3410, 3190, 3250, 2860, 2830, 3160, 2820, 2780, 2900, 2810, 2580, 2520, 2430]
x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float64)
y = [127, 134, 136 ,139, 140, 141, 148, 149, 151, 154, 155, 157, 159, 167, 168, 171]
y = np.asarray(y, dtype=np.float64)

#liner regression
# curve fitting
attributes,variances = curve_fit(linreg,x,y)
# estimated y
y_modeled = x*attributes[0]+attributes[1]
# plot true and modeled results
plot(x,y,'ob',markersize=2)
plot(x,y_modeled,'-r',linewidth=1)
show()

# exponential regression
#called in curve fitting model
def expon(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

#exponential
# curve fitting
attributes,variances = curve_fit(expon,x,y)
# estimated y
y_modeled = x*attributes[0]+attributes[1]
# plot true and modeled results
plot(x,y,'ob',markersize=2)
plot(x,y_modeled,'-r',linewidth=1)
show()


# logarithmic function
def logar(x, p1,p2):
  return p1*np.log(x)+p2
#logarithmic
# curve fitting
attributes,variances = curve_fit(logar,x,y)
# estimated y
y_modeled = x*attributes[0]+attributes[1]
# plot true and modeled results
plot(x,y,'ob',markersize=2)
plot(x,y_modeled,'-r',linewidth=1)
show()

#power curve function? MAybe? 
def powerlaw(x,a,b):
    return a*(x**b)

#power curves
# curve fitting
attributes,variances = curve_fit(powerlaw,x,y)
# estimated y
y_modeled = x*attributes[0]+attributes[1]
# plot true and modeled results
plot(x,y,'ob',markersize=2)
plot(x,y_modeled,'-r',linewidth=1)
show()
```

When I run the linear regression model the line fits the data. However, whenever I run the other curve fitting options to line is WAY above the data points. It doesn't fit the data at all.

Thank you! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Our TAs are on strike, so I have no one that is available to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the models correctly. Try these, which have the form "function(x, pointer_to_parameters)"

```
y_modeled = linreg(x, *attributes)
y_modeled = expon(x, *attributes)
y_modeled = logar(x, *attributes)
y_modeled = powerlaw(x, *attributes)
```

With these, I  get excellent plots from your code.